# get function in route FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi

Is it possible to pass a function to a route so that it is then called?
i tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
app = FastAPI()

class GetFunction(BaseModel):
    function: Callable


def hello():
    return print("Hello world")


@app.post("/datalore")
def datalore(function: GetFunction):
    function()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a function"? Is it mean you want to choose it by some request parameters or what?

Comment: May be you should check dependency injection? Seems like you may be looking for something like that https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/

Comment: puf, for example, I make an api request with parameters {"function": "hello"} and function hello(), if defined, is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way to do that is just get dictionary of functions you would like to call

```py
app = FastAPI()

def hello():
    print("Hello!")

@app.post("/datalore")
def datalore(function: str):
    func_dict = {"hello": hello}
    func_to_call = func_dict[function]
    return func_to_call()
```